# Understanding dateFormatter in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, swift4

I'm having trouble understanding date formatter in Swift. I'm parsing my date from server in this format `2018-02-05T14:44:01Z` and because of that I set DateFormatter like this `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`.

After that, I'm converting it to Date like this `dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateFromServer)`. And that's ok, it works (on a device with 24h time format) and I understand why.

But if I run this on device with 12h time format `dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateFromServer)` it returns `nil`. I have to add `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` for it to work on both 12/24h formats.

So my question is: Why should I add .locale if I already set my date format with `HH`. Shouldn't dateFormatter automatically convert it to users local settings? Also when I add `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` I lose PM/AM in formated string from date [`HH:MM` (yes I know HH is for 24h)]

Comment: Apple covers this. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look

Comment: @rmaddy that is one great link!

Answer (score 2):

Your format string doesn't match your actual date string. I guess the formatter is trying a backup, locale-specific format when the `dateFormat` doesn't match the string. You should be using this format string:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"
```

Or, if your deployment target is iOS 10 or later (or at least macOS 10.12, tvOS 10, or watchOS 3), you should use `ISO8601DateFormatter` instead:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let dateString = "2018-02-05T14:44:01Z"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
print(date)

# Output:
Optional(2018-02-05 14:44:01 +0000)
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question being asked in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hadn't seen that QA before.

Comment: I'm actually using the correct string in my code, this is a typo in the question, but thanks anyway :). Also, I believe this won't work on 12h device.